# How can I copy a large number of small JSON files in an AWS S3 folder structure to a Redshift instance?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

The question:   How can I copy a large number of small JSON files in an AWS S3 folder structure to a Redshift instance?

The problem:  Naturally, everything is fine in the dev environment, but the COPY command takes so long in prod that it aborts. My guess is that it fails not due to the total size of the data (albeit substantial), but the number of files to COPY (several thousand).

This is called from a lambda function that runs daily. The function runs the following SQL (truncated for brevity).

```
CREATE TABLE my_staging_table (
    profileid integer ENCODE bytedict,
    siteid integer ENCODE runlength,
    -- other columns...
)
DISTKEY(profileid)
SORTKEY(profileid);

COPY my_staging_table
from 's3://bucket/staging/files/20231016/'
credentials XYZ
MAXERROR 1000
ACCEPTINVCHARS
BLANKSASNULL
json 's3://path/file-jsonpaths.json';
```

I don't have much liberty to modify any upstream system. Does anyone have any idea how I can make the import from S3 to Redshift more performant?? Thank you!

Comment: You should try AWS Glue https://hevodata.com/learn/json-to-redshift/#b2 with reading files in larger groups https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/grouping-input-files.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is S3 and not really Redshift.  S3 is an object store and as such object names need to be mapped to (a copy of) the actual stored information in the S3 service.  This mapping takes time, while small it still adds up.  Referencing a file on S3 takes .5 - .75 seconds and then the data transfer can happen.  Redshift can read in parallel but only to the extent equal to the number of slices in the cluster.  So the file reads by each slice are serialized and each new file needs .5+ seconds to be referenced.

When the files are very small the transfer of the data takes only a small fraction of a second. The file reference time is far greater and transfer time from S3 which is why this pattern of small file storage is not recommended for large amounts of data that need to be processed together.

Preprocessing these files into larger files is generally the recommendation here.  A large number of parallel Lambda functions can combine these files quickly as the level of parallelism can be much greater than Redshift.  You say this isn’t an option but addressing this should be on your long-term improvements list.

One possible way to improve the speed here is to use Spectrum to load the data.  S3 is a very large cluster itself it may be able to use greater parallelism in loading the files and providing the data to Redshift.  The downside is that the files will need to be correct - no MAXERROR or ACCEPTINVCHAR options available.  So this may not help you even if it is faster.